# Insert an image into a post by API

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, attachments

By using the code below, I can create a new post and upload an image to wordpress's `upload` directory as a attachment through a form's submitted data.

```
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_author' => $user_ID,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_category' => array(3)
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    }
    if ($_FILES) {
        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
            if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
            }
            $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
        }   
    }
```

I want to insert an image to post, not replace the featured image so `set_post_thumbnail()` function is not appropriate. I found that if I manually insert an image to post, it will generated the HTML code likes:

```
<a href="http://192.168.1.12/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/H530U_08.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-136" title="HARP_SH530U_0" src="http://192.168.1.12/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/HARP_SH530U_08-300x167.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="167" /></a>
```

So which API would provide the function of inserting image to post, likes generating the HTML code above and not replacing the featured image?

Thanks

Comment: i think what you have to do is generate the neccessary html & append it to the `post_content` used in `wp_insert_post`, then use `wp_update_post` to update the new content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the uploaded image as the post thumbnail via,

```
update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
```

Example...

```
if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
        if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
        }
        $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
    }   
}

update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
```

If you are uploading an array of images, then you might wish to specify which image by referencing the key,

```
$file[0] //for the first image in the array
$file[1] //for the second image in the array
$file[2] //for the third image in the array
etc...
```

...but that should not be necessary when uploading a single image.

#### Update:

Based on your comments, if you want to insert the image at the beggining of or before your post content its probably best you filter the `the_content` function like so,

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_img_to_post', 20 );

function insert_img_to_post( $content ) {

    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    if ( is_single() )

        $content = sprintf(
            '<img class="post-icon" src="%s" alt="Post icon" title=""/>',
            wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true )),
            $content
        );

    return $content;
}
```

...add this function as a separate function/filter in your functions.php file. Do not try and bundle it within your `wp_insert_post` function as it will not work. This is intended to run by itself, hooking onto `the_content` filter, inserting the image at the top of the post before the content, then appending the content beneath it.

This is currently running on a single post page (`is_single`) if you want it to run on something else, like a page, then change to `is_page` or any other conditional tag that meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I test that if I use your code, there are none image insert to post; On the other hand, if I put `update_post_meta` under the line of `$attach_id`, I will replaced the featured image.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I just re-read, I thought you wanted to set the featured image of the post. But rather, you want to insert the image into the body of the content right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I want to insert the image into the body of the content.

Comment: Where abouts? The begining, the end or somewhere in the middle (anywhere in the middle, i.e. amongst text).

Comment: I think inserting the image to the begining of the content. Thanks

Comment: I have put the function `insert_img_to_post` into function.php, but where should `add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_img_to_post', 20 );
` to be placed?

Comment: That goes with the function `insert_img_to_post`, without it, that function can not be initialized without your intervention, nor will it filter the content. So copy the whole snippet I provided and place it into your functions.php file, exactly as you see it.

Comment: Sorry I got `Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_filter() in /var/www/wp/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3636 ` when I placed whole snippet in the end of functions.php

Comment: Which functions.php file are you placing that in? Its supposed to go in your theme folder functions.php file, not in wp-includes/functions.php. If you are editing files there, then stop, never edit files in the core install directories. Only your theme directory, or if you are creating a plugin, your plugin directory.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't get it to work. I will try it later and update the status. Thanks for your help, I will mark your answer as accepted later. Upvoted

Comment: `get_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true )` just return the attachment ID, I tried to use `wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true ))` to get the attachment url by its id. Finally it works. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake - half asleep! But glad its working now. I will amend my code.